# How to maintain control of numerous event racing scenarios in a platform of growing complexity?

Tags: events, microservices, azureservicebus, event-driven-design, eda

I have a Voucher Service which listens to incoming sales, and updates vouchers based on what has been purchased/returned etc.

So we consume a *SaleCompletedEvent*, which may put vouchers into a 'redeemed' or 'available' state.

However it's not just sales which can change the state of a voucher, other things in the platform such as a *VoucherRedeemedEvent* may also arrive at any time and change the state of vouchers. In this scenario, the redemption of a voucher had nothing to do with a sale.

We therefore encounter racing issues across multiple Event topics: we can't guarantee *SaleCompletedEvent* and *VoucherRedeemedEvent* will arrive in the order they were created, and therefore we might process these events out of logical sequence and end up with a voucher in the wrong state.

As the number of events in my platform grows, I'm considering putting all these types of events (which can affect a shared resource) on the same message bus topic so that they'll at least arrive to consumes in the intended order. But what are other approaches used to solve this type of problem as platforms grow in the number of events, and thus racing complexity?

Comment: It sounds like you have a workflow rather than just individual event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rethink the messages you send. If there's one event in the real life (a sale), then only emit one message.

If I got this right, if a voucher is used during a sale, you send a *VoucherRedeemedEvent* followed by a *SaleCompletedEvent*. I suggest that you only emit the *SaleCompletedEvent*, and you include the information that a voucher has been used into it. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Good assessment, though the challenge here is that a voucher may be redeemed retrospectively away from a sale - for example manually by some business process which allows this

Comment: It is then a different real life event, which will occur far after the sale, so you will not have your racing condition issue.

Comment: If the events are published to different topics, there's no intrinsic guarantee that they'll be consumed in the same order (if the events are timestamped with when they're considered to have happened (which isn't necessarily the timestamp of the message on the bus), it's possible for consumers to do things like watermarks... note that the period of uncertainty is natural and an accurate representation of things).

Comment: @FBryant87 note that if your domain has the idea of a voucher being allowed to be redeemed retrospectively arbitrarily far in the future, it is not possible to know within an arbitrary finite period of time with absolute certainty whether the voucher is actually available.  Your options become, at that point, deciding whether or not you embrace the uncertainty (analogous to choosing availability in the CAP theorem) and have your system make educated guesses (likely being able to revise its guesses) or limit the time period for retrospective redemption so that you can have certainty (C in CAP).